# Inheriting traits in c++

Tags: c++, templates, struct, traits

I am creating a trait in c++ which takes as template input another trait I made.
However, when I run this code I get the following compiler error :

> error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2) template<\Measure<\int v, Unit u> a>

The code is the following:

```
enum class Unit { km, m, cm };


template<int v, Unit u>
struct Measure
{
public:
    static const int value = v;
    static const Unit unit = u;
};


template< Measure<int v, Unit u> a>
struct Measure_add
{
public:
    static const int value = a::value;
    static const Unit unit = a::unit;
};
```

The usage should be:

```
std::cout << Measure_add< Measure<4, Unit::m> >::value << std::endl;
```

And this should give:

> 4

Answer (score 3):

`Measure_add` can be inherited from `Measure` in the following way:

```
template<class>
struct Measure_add;

template<int v, Unit u>
struct Measure_add<Measure<v, u>> : Measure<v, u> {};

static_assert(Measure_add<Measure<4, Unit::m>>::value == 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what this is supposed to mean:

```
template< Measure<int v, Unit u> a>
```

You probably wanted this instead:

```
template< typename  a>
struct Measure_add
{
public:
    static const int value = a::value;
    static const Unit unit = a::unit;
};
```

Now you can instantiate it via

```
using m_add = Measure_add< Measure<4,Unit::m> >;
```

Comment: That makes sense, however I want the usage to be like this:
    ` std::cout << Measure_add< Measure<4, Unit::m> >::value << std::endl; `
So the typename must be of type Measure<int a, Unit b>

Comment: @suitendaal erm no, and yes. The type you use as parameters can be an instantiation of `Measure`, see edit